# problems with updating tidyverse in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, updates

```
Fehler: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]): Namensraum ‘vctrs’ 0.2.0 ist bereits geladen, aber >= 0.2.1 wird gefordert
```

This is the error I get whenever I `library(tidyverse)`

So I did this:

```
installing.packages("vctrs") 
library(vctrs)
installing.packages("tidyverse",dependencies=T)
library(tidyverse)
```

But I get the same Error. Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried removing the previous installation beforehand? `remove.packages("tidyverse")`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you dont have the right version of the "vctrs" package, try: `install.packages("vctrs")`
instead of `installing...`.

If that doesn't work open RStudio->Tools->Check for Package Updates
then Select All->Install Updates

Comment: I did it, but I get the same Error. I also restarted the Rsession but that does not help either...

Comment: I uninstalled R and installed it again and I updated RStudio to the latest version and then I installed tidyverse and it functions now! I do not know why it happened but now it works again

Comment: That is quite logical since reinstalling R caused it to install the latest version of all packages. So apparently something went wrong when R tried to install a newer verison of the 'vctrs' package.